# Как сделать правильную выборку из БД?

Tags: python, flask

Пишу лайки к комментариям блога.
Нугуглил вот такое решение.
Но работает, только для первого комментария. Да-да, я в курсе, что там написано `.first()`.
Не знаю, как выбрать именно тот, комментарий, возле которого нажата кнопка. 
Что скажете?

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    like = Commentary.query.filter_by(key=post_id).first()  
    like.like += 1 
    db.session.commit()
```

Шаблон:

```
<form method='POST'>
          <input type='submit' value="+1" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

**Обновление**

```
@users_blueprint.route('/post/<int:post_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post(post_id):

    form = CommentaryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        commentary = Commentary(
            text = form.text.data,
            key = post_id
        )
        db.session.add(commentary)
        db.session.commit()

    post_page = BlogPost.query.filter_by(id=post_id).first()
    comments = Commentary.query.filter_by(key=post_id).all()

    return render_template('post.html', post_id=post_id, post_page=post_page, form=form, comments=comments)
```

Comment: И все-таки уточните, если можно, внутри какой функции находится код:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        like = Commentary.query.filter_by(key=post_id).first()  
        like.like += 1 
        db.session.commit()

и какие у нее есть аргументы?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.